# what happens when Linux Kernel thread exits with locks held

Tags: linux-kernel

What happens when Linux kernel thread exits with spin lock held?

I see in the function : static inline void schedule_debug(struct task_struct *prev)
which is in __schedule , there is a check  :

if (unlikely(in_atomic_preempt_off() && prev->state != TASK_DEAD)
        __schedule_bug(prev);

which avoids the check of preemption disable for exiting threads.

So, does the kernel explicitly makes sure the locks are released or it just lets the kernel go into dead lock state if the thread doesn't handle it?

Also, what about other locks like mutex and semaphores?

Comment: which spin lock are you talking?

Comment: Why can't you check it by yourself? - it seems that test case could be implemented easily. As i understand your question, you will get ordinary deadlock on your globally visible spinlock. Don't see any problems with catching this fact. Why exiting thread should take care of unrelated global spinlocks?